# How to compare values of two objects of the same type?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

I need to write unit tests for a Flutter project and I would be happy if there is a function that can go through all properties of two different objects of a same type to make sure that all values are same.

Code sample:

```
void main() {
  test('startLoadingQuizReducer sets isLoading true', () {
    var initState = QuizGameState(null, null, null, false);
    var expectedState = QuizGameState(null, null, null, true);

    var action = StartLoadingQuiz();
    var actualState = quizGameReducer(initState, action);
    // my test fails here 
    expect(actualState, expectedState);
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

### How to override `==` for equality testing

Here is an example of overriding the `==` operator so that you can compare two objects of the same type.

```
class Person {
  final String name;
  final int age;
  
  const Person({this.name, this.age});
  
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    identical(this, other) ||
    other is Person &&
    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
    name == other.name &&
    age == other.age;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode ^ age.hashCode;
}
```

The example above comes from [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-equatable-package-simplify-equality-comparisons-1a96a3fc4864), which is recommending that you use the [Equitable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/equatable) package to simplify the process. [This article](https://work.j832.com/2014/05/equality-and-dart.html) is also worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the [equality operator](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) in your `QuizGameState` class.

Comment: And don't forget to override hashCode if you do that.  Otherwise, Set and others will break.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the answer provided here, if the object has a list in it you will have to compare the list separately like explained [Compare lists for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006947/how-to-compare-values-of-two-objects-of-the-same-type)